# Discretization of one-dimensional inhomogeneus Schröedinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, differential-equations

I was reading this article on numerical solutions for the non homogeneous schröedinger equation and when proposing a discretized solution it states:

if we consider the time-dependent schröedinger equation:

\begin{equation*}
\left( i\hbar \frac{\partial }{\partial t} -H\right) \ \psi ( t) \ =\ N( t)
\end{equation*}
the corresponding homogeneous equation has a solution which can be written in terms of the evolution operator:

\begin{equation*}
\psi _{h}( t+\Delta t) \ =\ e^{-iH\Delta t/\hbar } \psi _{h}( t).
\end{equation*}

On the other hand, the non-homogeneous equation has a particular solution:
\begin{equation*}
\psi _{nh}( t+\Delta t) \ =\ -\frac{i}{\hbar } e^{-iH( t+\Delta t) /\hbar } \ \int _{t}^{t+\Delta t} e^{iHt'/\hbar } N( t') dt'
\end{equation*}
The general solution can therefore be written as:
\begin{equation*}
\psi ( t) \ =\ \psi _{h}( t) +\psi _{nh}( t)
\end{equation*}
with the boundary condition value inserted such that $\psi ( t_{0}) \ =\ \psi _{h}( t_{0}) \ =\ \phi $

where $\phi$ is  a  normalized  function  of  the  spatial coordinate(s). Thus the solution with the appropriate boundary condition may be obtained by increasing t (starting at $t_0$) by steps equal to $\Delta t$ using:

$\psi ( t+\Delta t) = e^{-iH\Delta t/\hbar } \psi( t) -\frac{i}{\hbar } e^{-iH\Delta t/\hbar } \ \int _{0}^{\Delta t} e^{iH\ \theta /\hbar } N( \theta +t) d\theta $

---

I am having trouble understanding the last expression. If I take the general solution to be:

$\psi ( t) \ =\ \psi _{h}( t) +\psi _{nh}( t)$

then increasing in one time step I get:

$\psi (t+\Delta t) \ =\ \psi _{h}( t+\Delta t) +\psi _{nh}( t+\Delta t)$

and replacing with the expressions stated above I obtain:

$ e^{-iH\Delta t/\hbar } \psi _{h}( t) -\frac{i}{\hbar } e^{-iH( t+\Delta t) /\hbar } \ \int _{t}^{t+\Delta t} e^{iHt'/\hbar } N( t') dt'\ $

which using the substitution $\theta = t'-t$ in the integral leads to:

$\psi ( t+\Delta t) = e^{-iH\Delta t/\hbar } \psi _{h}( t) -\frac{i}{\hbar } e^{-iH\Delta t/\hbar } \ \int _{0}^{\Delta t} e^{iH\ \theta /\hbar } N( \theta +t) d\theta $

What I don't understand is why the article obtains $\psi(t)$ instead of $\psi _{h}( t)$ in the first term of the final expression. I figure it has to do with applying the boundary condition but I can't see how.

I attach the image with this particular deduction at the end, the paper's DOI is: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.90.063309 but I consider it is not necessary to understand the question.

[image]

Comment: From the definition of the solution to the nonhomogeneous solution you get $\psi_{nh}(t)=0$ (by letting $\Delta t=0$). Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, i thought about that but I also thought that maybe I was missing something because that would make $\psi(t) = \psi_h(t)$ and that makes no sense to me

Comment: Then I think you should try to make sense of this issue first because the way $\psi_{nh}(t)$ is defined its trivially 0.

Comment: I suppose that definition might not be valid for $\Delta t$ = 0 since $\Delta t$  is infinitesimal but I'm not sure. I think the definition has to be correct because it's a peer reviewed paper after all.

Comment: Actually using the fact that $\psi_{nh}(t)=0$, your question may be answered because then in the first term of the last expression you can use either $\psi_h(t)$ or $\psi(t)$